# Equivalent of Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor in more recent .NET version?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have this a Windows Form app that creates a field in the grid where I can select a file. I believe this is for .net 2.0.

```
[Editor(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor),
      typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    public string XMLFile4
    {
        get { return xmlFile4; }
        set { xmlFile4 = value; }
    }
```

[file open dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuEMv.gif)

What would the the equivalent of the code above for a more recent version of Windows Form, maybe for .net 4.0? Like how could I make it open a file dialog so I can select a file to fill in for this property

```
[Display(GroupName = "Xml", Name = "XMLFile0", Order = 0)]
        public string XMLFile0
        {
            get { return xmlFile0; }
            set { xmlFile0 = value; }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor is still available in .NET 4.6.1, and your code will work as is.

Make sure you have a reference to System.Design.dll in your project and that you are targeting the full framework and not just the client profile.

Comment: I was told that System.Design.dll is not compatible with the framework that generate this kind of design. http://d.pr/i/1bjrW if Im not mistaken this is "windows presentation foundation". System.Design.dll gets removed from my project automatically. It's a ninjatrader 8 project.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry the type of project I'm trying to update is a WPF project, so I was told the System.Design isnt' compatible.